# Sleeping a specific mouse movement with C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to control the mouse movement in an application, so far I'm using HWND GetActiveWindow with PostMessage, it works fine but I want to add a little bit of delay. I added Sleep() and it's working as expected, sleeping the Active Window for X.. ms.

My question is, is there a way I can make the Sleep function to be triggered only when I click on a specific mouse button and then stop it immediately, or something close to this?
Thank you, appreciate all your help.

Comment: WM_LBUTTONDOWN or similar messages.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same principles apply to mouse input. In particular note, that [replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call the Sleep() function only when a specific mouse button is pressed:

```
UINT button = GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam);  
if (button == XBUTTON1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

See also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/mouse-input

Comment: Thank you for your help, it seems the code isn't doing anything though.

Comment: This is an incomplete block of code based on the Microsoft support article. Please post here your code and I will do my best to help you

Comment: int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while (true)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    x += 10;
    y += 10;
}

Comment: I still don't understand your code and what are you trying to do. Please upload the entire source code and post here a link to download it

Comment: I basically just want to add a delay to when I click on the right mouse button.